# in django signals creating new user and alongwith filelds also from django models(by default add cash_amount and data)

Tags: python, django

This my models:

```
class UserBillingHistory(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, default="Free 100Mb on sign-up and Buy $40 and get 100Mb" 
)
    cash_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    data = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=False, null=False)
    is_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    job = models.ForeignKey("Job", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    @property
    def user_can_view(self, user):
        return (self.user == user)

    def user_can_edit(self, user):
        return (self.user == user)

    def user_can_delete(self, user):
        return (self.user == user)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/userbillinghistorys/%s/" % self.id

    def cash_amount(self):
        return "$%s" % 0

    def data(self):
        return 100 * 1024 * 1024
```

This my signals:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
    """Receiver to create authoriasation tokens for users"""

    if kwargs.get('raw'):
        return  # ignore for loading fixtures

    if created:
        Token.objects.create(user=instance)
        UserBillingHistory.objects.create(user=instance)

        if settings.NEW_USER_EMAIL is not None:
            send_email(
                "Spotless data - new user",
                "New user with email %s has signed up" % instance.email,
                "Spotless Data<team@spotlessdata.com>",
                settings.NEW_USER_EMAIL
                )
```

By above code i am able to see by default cash_amount=0 and data=1978344
Add a signal post_save on the User model, to create a record in billing history with cash=0 and data = 100 * 1024 * 1024.
This should give each use 100Mb of free data when they create an account
But i am getting below error. CAn you please suggest regards it.

unicodeencodeerror 'charmap' codec can't encode character u' u2019' in position

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with your description field, while saving it use `unicode(description)`

Comment: Hi niranj, The bug is getting while new user signup and i think not a model issue. If model issue please give proper information thanks.

Comment: The error is unicodencode error, what i am guessing is the only character field in your model is description. Okay let that be, can you share what you gave in the `description` field. Also share the complete strack trace

Comment: description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False, default="Free 100Mb on sign-up and Buy $40 and get 100Mb")

Comment: I was not asking for this what is the actual you give in the text box before clicking on the save button?

Comment: def __str__(self):
        return self.description

Comment: change it to def __unicode__(self): return self.description

Comment: After changes i am getting in signals AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via UserBillingHistory instances

Comment: Great. Guess the question you have asked in this post is answered amd it worked fine. Post this as a separate qst, Post the full stack trace for further investigation. Also dont forget to mark this as the correct answer